# If A and B are independent sequences of Bernoulli trials w/ different p, what is the probability that success occurs in A before success occurs in B?

Tags: probability, geometric-series

Suppose a sequence of [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) continues until a success occurs. For two independent such sequences, say $A$ and $B$, with respective success-probabilities $a$ and $b$, what is the probability that $A$ is shorter than $B$?

Here's an example of what I mean: Suppose that I have two unfair coins. Coin 1 has a probability of coming up heads of $\frac{1}{3}$, and coin 2 has a probability of coming up heads of $\frac{2}{3}$. I flip both coins at the same time. What is the probability that Coin 1 is heads before coin 2? Let $C_n$ be the number of flips it takes coin $n$ to come up heads.

$P(C_1<C_2) = ?$

Comment: I need an information : does the play stop if both get heads ?

Comment: Good question but could have been worded a bit better with perhaps a few examples.

Comment: @Max - This is a good question. You should not have put it on hold. How can it be "off topic" when it is clearly a math problem? This is annoying and unwarranted.

Comment: @Did - This is a good question. You should not have put it on hold. How can it be "off topic" when it is clearly a math problem? This is annoying and unwarranted.

Comment: @Laurent Duval - This is a good question, you should not have put it on hold. How can it be "off topic" when it is clearly a math problem? This is annoying and unwarranted.

Comment: @Adam Hughes - This is a good question. You should not have put it on hold. How can it be "off topic" when it is clearly a math problem? This is annoying and unwarranted.

Comment: @heropup - This is a good question. You should not have put it on hold. How can it be "off topic" when it is clearly a math problem? This is annoying and unwarranted.

Comment: Your example suggests that your question is misstated and should rather be something like the following: 
*Suppose a sequence of [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) continues until a success occurs. For two independent such sequences, say $A$ and $B$, with respective success-probabilities $a$ and $b$, what is the probability that $A$ is shorter than $B$?*
This is equivalent to asking *If $X\sim \text{Geometric}(a)$ and $Y\sim \text{Geometric}(b)$ are independent, then what is $P(X<Y)$?*

Comment: @r.e.s. : yes, it's not a classical wording but most puzzles are written like that. I don't see the opposition with the example ... The only problem is that the question poster is absent ...

Comment: Shame  cuz it is a good question and one that I could not guess correctly or solve correctly without simulation.

Comment: @Gigno -  I've edited the question, so perhaps it will get re-opened. Please correct me if I have misinterpreted your intended meaning.

Comment: @r.e.s. I've always understood a geometric distribution to be a series of Bernoulli trials iterated until the first success. Thus, I'm not sure how your rewording is in anyway different, more clear or otherwise, than the original question.

Comment: Ordinarily, *geometric series* refers to a certain type of (non-random) sum, whereas the question is presumably about a sequence of Bernoulli trials (random variables), for which certain *probabilities* turn out to be given by a geometric series. Distinct from this is a *geometric distribution*, which is the distribution of the random variable $N$, where $N$ is the index of the first success in the sequence of Bernoulli trials $X_1,X_2,...$.

Comment: (cont'd) It seems clear that you were referring to a sequence of Bernoulli trials carried out until a success occurs, but you mistakenly called that random sequence a "geometric series".

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward approach is to sum a series. Instead, we will condition on the results of the first toss. Let $a$ be the probability Coin 1 lands head, and let $b$ be the probability Coin 2 lands head. Let $x$ be the probability  Coin 1 lands head before Coin 2 does.

If on the first toss Coin 1 lands heads, and Coin 2 does not, then Player $1$ has won. This has probability $a(1-b)$.

Player 1 can also win if both coins land tail on the first toss, but Player 1 still ultimately wins. The conditional probability Player 1 ultimately wins given both got tails on the first toss is $x$. Thus, by the Law of Total Probability,
$$x=a(1-b)+(1-a)(1-b)x.$$
Solve for $x$.

Answer (score 3):

We solve it by using the same basic principles used to find the probability mass of a geometric series.

$C_1$ will happen before $C_2$ if: there are numerous events in which neither occurs followed by an event which the first coin shows heads *and* the second does not.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C_1< C_2) ~=~& \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p_{1\cup 2})^k p_{1\cap 2^\complement}\\[1ex] ~=~& p_1(1-p_2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p_1-p_2+p_1p_2)^k\\[1ex] =~&\dfrac{p_1(1-p_2)}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2} \\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{(1/3)(1-2/3)}{1/3+2/3-2/9}\\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{1}{7}\end{align}$$

If we do not exclude the event of a tie

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C_1\leqslant C_2) =~&\dfrac{p_1}{p_1+p_1-p_1p_2} \\[1ex] =~& \dfrac{3}{7}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

A simple simulation of $100,000,000$ cases where the $1/3$rd probability coin gets heads before the $2/3$rds probability coin is showing very close to $1/7$.  I got $14,287,277$ which is very close to $14,285,714$ expected value. Note that the Rand() function, (with no parameter passed), returns a real number between $0$ and $1$.

```
* A program to check the probability of a 1/3rd probability head biased coin coming up heads before a 2/3rds
* probability head biased coin comes up heads if both are tossed simultaneously multiple times.

sec = SECONDS()  && check the timer so we get the start time and check how long program takes to run.
=RAND(-1)        && initialize random number generator to give different random sequence each time program runs.
good = 0         && counter for # of times 1/3rd bias coin comes up heads before 2/3 bias coin.
its = 100000000  && 100 million iterations should be enough.

FOR i = 1 TO its
 STORE .f. TO c1h, c2h     && c1h = flag for coin 1 is heads.  .f. = false.
 DO WHILE !c1h AND !c2h    && loop while both coins are tails.
  c1h = INT(3*RAND()) = 1  && 1 chance  in 3 of this being true.
  c2h = INT(3*RAND()) # 1  && 2 chances in 3 of this being true.
  IF c1h AND !c2h          && coin 1 is heads but coin 2 is tails.
   good = good + 1         && that is a winner.
  ENDIF
 ENDDO
NEXT i

? good, SECONDS() - sec  && ? means show to the screen (standard output).
```

Runtime was about $2$ minutes and output was $14287277$ and $125.302$ (seconds).

Comment: This is an extremely simple simulation.  I just have $2$ random number variables that get a random integer $0,1$, or $2$.  The $1/3$rd head bias coin is simulated by checking if the random integer is a $1$.  The $2/3$rd bias coin is simulated by checking if the random integer is not a $1$.  Then I just loop until someone gets a head and I only count the winners if the $1/3$rd coin is heads before the other coin is heads.

Comment: @ igael - ok there is my code.  I did what you asked and put the tabs before each line.  I wish I knew how to make the font smaller so  all the comments would fit into the viewport.  I would like to get  rid of the scrollbar.  My screen is in $1280x1024$ resolution and I still see that scrollbar.

Comment: @igael  - Not sure what you mean by this.  We already know the probabilities of both coins coming up heads and the OP is just asking what is the probability of coin $1$ getting a head first which is what my simulation shows.  My answer matches that of Graham Kemp's.  If both get head on the same flip then that is not a "win" for coin # 1.  I only count the cases where coin $1$ gets a head before coin $2$ does but I stop the trial when ANY head is seen.  I am trying $1$ billion decisions now which should take about $20$ minutes to complete.

Comment: I got the results from the $1$ billion trials.  I got $142,858,629$.  The expected value of $1/7$ would give $142,857,143$.  Those are VERY close.

Comment: @igael - The OP's example is coin 1 getting a  head before coin 2.  So our trial would be to flip both biased coins simultaneously (or simulate it) until either is a head.  We have to stop the trial  if coin 2 gets a head cuz otherwise coin 1 would never get a head  first and we would get "stuck" so if coin 2 gets the  head first we end the trial and start a new one.  So here we are counting the number of trials that result in coin 1 getting the head first.  Ties and coin 2 wins both count as "losses" to coin 1.  That is my interpretation.

Comment: @igael - A tie is a failed win for coin # 1.  If they tie, then there is no way either can win outright so it is pointless to continue the trial so I start a new trial.  However, the tie DOES count as a trial.  I count a tie as basically the same as a win for coin # 2 since coin # 1 did NOT win.

Comment: @igael  - Yes that is what my code looks for that I published.  The OP doesn't clearly state what we should do if both coins flip simultaneously to heads but it is reasonable to assume that is a fail for coin 1, we end that trial, and start a new trial, which is exactly what my code does.  The answer I get is $1/7$ or about $14.2857$% .  Someone else got the same answer as me.

Comment: @igael - So if my answer is "false", where is the error in my code?  The code is shown.  It seems correct to me  just like I feel confident in the other code I have for the C vs. D in another post.